# Problems in IE7/IE8 with my header on my site

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Can someone please help a poor girl out with a few problems i'm having only in IE 7 and IE 8.
First there is a space at the top of my webpage and i have no clue why... And the page is also wider then normal ?. The nav menu i have a fix for im pretty sure. but those 2 problems i have no clue where there coming from. http://tshirthideout.com/.

Comment: Have you tried using IE8's dev tools window to analyse the layout and see what CSS is being applied?

Comment: where do i find these dev tools

Comment: IE8 and higher comes with it included. Press F12. (same key also actives similar tools in other browsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its all with your ie.css

your .site says to add a margin-top of 48px and also add a padding left and right of 40px.